You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders - @antv
I am usign Line Chart from import { Line } from '@ant-design/plots';
Since yesterday My build is getting failed with this error:
Failed to compile.
./node_modules/@antv/g2/node_modules/@antv/component/esm/crosshair/html-theme.js 5:22
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:22)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| // tooltip 相关 dom 的 css 类名
| import * as CssConst from './css-const';
> export default _a = {},
| // css style for tooltip
| _a["" + CssConst.CONTAINER_CLASS] = {

When I check this file, there is the following code:
var _a;
import Theme from '../util/theme';
// tooltip 相关 dom 的 css 类名
import * as CssConst from './css-const';
export default (_a = {},
    // css style for tooltip
    _a["" + CssConst.CONTAINER_CLASS] = {
        position: 'absolute',
        visibility: 'visible',
        // @2018-07-25 by blue.lb 这里去掉浮动，火狐上存在样式错位
        // whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
        zIndex: 8,
        transition: 'visibility 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), ' +
            'left 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), ' +
            'top 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)',
        boxShadow: '0px 0px 10px #aeaeae',
        borderRadius: '3px',
        color: 'rgb(87, 87, 87)',
        fontSize: '12px',
        fontFamily: Theme.fontFamily,
        lineHeight: '20px',
        padding: '10px 10px 6px 10px',
    },
    _a["" + CssConst.TITLE_CLASS] = {
        marginBottom: '4px',
    },
    _a["" + CssConst.LIST_CLASS] = {
        margin: '0px',
        listStyleType: 'none',
        padding: '0px',
    },
    _a["" + CssConst.LIST_ITEM_CLASS] = {
        listStyleType: 'none',
        marginBottom: '4px',
    },
    _a["" + CssConst.MARKER_CLASS] = {
        width: '8px',
        height: '8px',
        borderRadius: '50%',
        display: 'inline-block',
        marginRight: '8px',
    },
    _a["" + CssConst.VALUE_CLASS] = {
        display: 'inline-block',
        float: 'right',
        marginLeft: '30px',
    },
    _a["" + CssConst.CROSSHAIR_X] = {
        position: 'absolute',
        width: '1px',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)',
    },
    _a["" + CssConst.CROSSHAIR_Y] = {
        position: 'absolute',
        height: '1px',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)',
    },
    _a);
//# sourceMappingURL=html-theme.js.map

Now I don't have @ant-design/plots' directly installed. I tried doing that but it didn't worked.
These are the entries in my package json:
    "@ant-design/charts": "1.4.2",
    "@ant-design/graphs": "1.4.0",

Babel Config:
     babel: {
    presets: [
      [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          targets: {
            node: 'current',
          },
          loose: true,
        },
      ],
    ],
    plugins: [
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator', { loose: true }],
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
      ['@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods', { loose: true }],
      ['@babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object', { loose: true }],
      // Add any other Babel plugins if needed
    ],
  },

Any Help or info on this will be appreciated.
